# Convert multidimensional object to query string

Tags: javascript, php

I have an object:

```
{"f":{"cid":"325","field_name[10][0]":"133","field_name[10][1]":"132","price":"320|3600"}}
```

And I would like to convert this object to query string.
I'm using this function:

```
function toQueryString(obj, prefix) {
        var str = [];
        for(var p in obj) {
            var k = prefix ? prefix + "[" + p + "]" : p, v = obj[p];
            str.push(typeof v == "object" ?
              toQueryString(v, k) :
              encodeURIComponent(k) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(v));
        }
        return str.join("&");
}
```

But this function gives me result:

```
f[cid]=325&f[field_name[10][0]]=133&f[field_name[10][1]]=132&f[price]=320%7C3600
```

This is wrong as I can't get right result on my server side:

```
Array
(
    [f] => Array
        (
            [cid] => 325
            [field_name[10] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 133
                )

            [price] => 320|3600
        )
)
```

How can I solve this problem?
I think the right result will be something like this:

```
f[cid]=325&f[field_name[[10][0]]]=133&f[field_name[[10][1]]]=132&f[price]=320%7C3600
```

Comment: What kind of output are you looking to get?

Comment: @melight I am going to guess based on the tags that the OP wants a url query string that php will understand as a multidimensional array when it parses the GET variables.

Comment: I'd suggest (unless you are constrained) to instead pass it as urlencoded json. It is probably going to be less tricky to get right. You have to explicitly decode the json on the php side though

Comment: Barring that, I believe I remember a jquery plugin that does this. Serialize object, I think it is called.

Comment: I need pure javascript solution. Thanks.

Comment: As @TimSeguine suggested, you can use `JSON.stringify()` if you need a pure JavaScript solution.

Comment: What should be the expected output in php when you `print_r($_GET)` or `print_r($_POST)`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I changed your function a little in order to correct the nested query strings:

```
function toQueryString(obj, prefix) {
    var str = [], k, v;
    for(var p in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {continue;} // skip things from the prototype
        if (~p.indexOf('[')) {
            k = prefix ? prefix + "[" + p.substring(0, p.indexOf('[')) + "]" + p.substring(p.indexOf('[')) : p;
// only put whatever is before the bracket into new brackets; append the rest
        } else {
            k = prefix ? prefix + "[" + p + "]" : p;
        }
        v = obj[p];
        str.push(typeof v == "object" ?
          toQueryString(v, k) :
          encodeURIComponent(k) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(v));
    }
    return str.join("&");
}
```

Running this function on your original object now gives us this query string:

```
f[cid]=325&f[field_name][10][0]=133&f[field_name][10][1]=132&f[price]=320|3600
```

If we pass this to a PHP page told to `print_r($_GET)`, it gives us:

```
Array
(
    [f] => Array
        (
            [cid] => 325
            [field_name] => Array
                (
                    [10] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 133
                            [1] => 132
                        )

                )

            [price] => 320|3600
        )

)
```

Exactly what you wanted, right?

Comment: When using `in`, it is generally considered good practice to  check `hasOwnProperty` in case someone modified the prototype.

Answer (score 1):

This question already has an answer that does what you want,  but I decided to explain the alternative that I hinted at in my comment because I think it is good to know more than one way of doing things.

It doesn't do what you want exactly,  but I think it is a simpler,  robuster, and more maintainable method of transmitting arbitrary objects.

```
function toQueryString(obj, name)  {
    return encodeURIComponent(name) + '=' +
        encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(obj));
}
```

On the php side (assuming `name` was `"foo"`),  all you have to do is:

```
$foo=json_decode($_GET["foo"], true);
```

The only bit of difficulty is that if you want to support certain versions of Internet Explorer, you have to use a polyfill for `JSON.stringify`,  but these are readily available.

The drawback is naturally an extra indirection, but I think there is a major benefit: you are pushing the burden of bug testing this to the browser manufacturers and (if necessary) the developers of whatever implementation of `JSON.stringify` you decide to use.

Granted that has the drawback of introducing a new dependency,  but I believe it is useful enough to warrant it.

Your mileage may vary.

Also: if you can send the data using a POST request,  than you can directly send the result of `JSON.stringify` as raw POST data without URL encoding it. In the PHP  side you  can fetch it with `json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true)`

Comment: This works only if you are willing to change the default behavior on php side, I think the PHP code should not have to worry about how the data is presented to it.

Comment: @mr1031011 The default behavior is nowhere standardized, not robust, and not easily supported client side. I agree with you inasmuch as it is not ideal. But this is the easiest thing to support robustly IMO if you have complete control of your stack. The accepted solution, while not bad, has some issues with certain types of data. This is a purely practical solution I came up with for dealing with it at the time when I had bugs caused by code similar to the accepted answer.

Comment: Caveat: I only do systems work nowadays, so I can't say confidently that I would still personally recommend my solution. It scratched my itch when I wrote it, and was simpler than any other alternative I found.

Comment: I do agree with you that is a good solution that can be used when the developer has access to both the frontend and backend code :)

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote this. It works for me.

```
let objToQueryString = function (obj, prefix) {
    let fields = [];
    if (obj && Object.keys(obj).length) {
        for (let i in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                if (typeof obj[i] === 'object') {
                    fields.push(objToQueryString(obj[i], prefix ? prefix + '[' + i + ']' : i));
                } else {
                    fields.push((prefix ? prefix + '[' + i + ']' : i) + '=' + (typeof obj[i] === 'undefined' ? '' : encodeURIComponent(obj[i])));
                }
            }
        }
    } else if (prefix) {
        fields.push(prefix + '=');
    }
    return fields.join('&');
};

objToQueryString({x: 1, y: 2, z: {a: 10, b: 20, c: {i: 100, j: null, k: {}}}}); //returns "x=1&y=2&z[a]=10&z[b]=20&z[c][i]=100&z[c][j]=&z[c][k]="
```

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript

```
declare global {
    interface Object {
        queryString: () => string;
    }
}    

if (!Object.prototype.queryString) {
    Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'queryString', {
        value: function () {
            var parts = [];
            let obj = this;
            for (var key in obj) {
                if (typeof obj[key] == 'object') {
                    for (var key2 in obj[key]) {
                        parts.push(`${encodeURIComponent(key)}[${encodeURIComponent(key2)}]` + '=' + encodeURIComponent(obj[key][key2]));
                    }
                } else if (typeof obj[key] == 'string') {
                    parts.push(encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(obj[key]));
                }
            }
            return "?" + parts.join('&');
        }
    });
}

input: {"test":{"convert":"querystring"}}
output: test[convert]=querystring
```

Answer (score -2):

```
function solution(inputString, objectName)
{
    var startingIndex =  inputString.replace(/'/g, "").indexOf('{')
    var endingIndex =  inputString.replace(/'/g, "").indexOf('}')
    var propertyValuePairs = inputString.replace(/'/g, "").substring(startingIndex + 1, endingIndex ).split(',')
    var propertyValues = new Array();

    $.each(propertyValuePairs , function(index, element){ 
        var elements = element.split(':'); propertyValues.push({property: elements[0], value: elements[1]}); 
    });

    var result = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < propertyValues.length; i++) {
         result += objectName + "[" + propertyValues[i].property + "]" + "=" + propertyValues[i].value + "&";
    }
    return result.substring(0, result.length - 1);
}
```

Comment: Several errors with badly named variables, and it won't work anyways.

Comment: all right, all right :-)  I did not invest much in the names indeed, and the version I pasted was not run because I hurried up to paste it here (and the code was built from copy+paste from my console's experiments). Now it runs and returns the expected result. As for "it won't always work" - it works for the scenario the OP asked ;)

Comment: When i tested it after fixing the names, it returned the same thing as the OP, which was not what he was looking for.

Comment: As far as I understand - my result: "f[cid]=325&f[field_name[10][0]]=133&f[field_name[10][1]]=132&f[price]=320|3600" is exactly what the OP wants. See him stating above "Running this function on your original object now gives us this query string:

f[cid]=325&f[field_name][10][0]=133&f[field_name][10][1]=132&f[price]=320|3600"

Comment: Its only drawback is that, as I said, it is hardwired to work with a single object only. I could make the solution better to decode as many objects are passed in the string, but this is beyond the scope of the problem posed, so I did not.

Comment: The problem is with the surrounding brackets. They prevent the deep array from parsing correctly. And why are you quoting my answer as the OP?

Comment: I see. In any case, only now I noticed the question was already solved. So not this time for me. Thanks.